# Reload screen after submitting form - Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am creating a Discord command creator app. I have the client talking to the server correctly and outputting what I want. The issue is that once I submit the form, the page doesn't refresh. Below I have the template and script.

```
<template>
  <form v-on:submit="addCommand">
    <div id="container" class="col-md-5 m-auto">
      <div class="card card-body">
        <h1 class="text-center mb-3"><i class="fab fa-discord"></i> Command Creator</h1>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="command">Command</label>
            <input type="text" v-model="command" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter a command." />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="output">Output</label>
            <input type="text" v-model="output" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter an output." />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Create</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Dashboard',
  data () {
    return {
      command: '',
      output: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addCommand (e) {
      this.axios.post('http://localhost:3000/server', {
        command: this.command,
        output: this.output
      })
      e.preventDefault()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: try to remove `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: For a Vue app, you probably don't *want* the page to refresh; that would reload the full app.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49599274/how-to-submit-a-form-in-vue-redirect-to-a-new-route-and-pass-the-parameters

Comment: When the page "refreshes" what are you trying to achieve?